# Configuring Emacs and Keyboard to work like my Windows set-up

Tags: keyboard

There are various differences between the default Windows installation of Emacs and the default installation on the Pi, things like Ctrl-Backspace, Ctrl-Left, Ctrl-Right and so on. Generally, the key sequences don't do anything on the Pi version.

Can anyone suggest how to make the Pi behave like the Windows version of Emacs?

Comment: You know of `M-x global-set-key`?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: Yes, I do know of that command. This isn't really about emacs I guess, the problem is that the keycodes differ between the Windows (or Ubuntu) versions and the Pi version. This *may* be the keyboard being used. For example, Ctrl-Backspace (I think) can be mapped in Win/Lin but I don't get the code at all on the Pi. I didn't want to write a dozens of global-set-key commands into my .emacs (I like to use the same one for all platforms). I'll get a more concrete example later.

Comment: Note that the bindings in the Windows distribution of Emacs are _very_ non-standard and if you want to have the same in _any_ Linux distribution you will need to do the necessary configuration yourself.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: When I press Ctrl-Backspace emacs gets a different keycode when running on the Pi than when it runs on any other platform, the view-lossage command has a different output. I'll update the question when I get home with some examples.

Comment: That is a matter of X server configuration.  Check xmodmap.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: I'm using a non x based terminal on the PI! (i.e the login tty)

Comment: @AwesomeUser: no, I haven't!